# Segfault occurs, GDB breaks on line, but running line after segfault shows no violation

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault

I have a program which is segfaulting at a specific line:

uint64_t smaller_num = *(uint64_t*)(smaller_base+index);

GDB successfully catches the segfault allowing me to debug the issue.  However, if I run the line from the GDB prompt, no memory access violation occurs:

(gdb) p smaller_num = *(uint64_t*)(smaller_base+index)

Can anyone provide some suggestions on how to debug this issue? I am at a loss of words and ideas because I verified that the memory at smaller_base+index exists.  Can it be something with the casting?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: providing more code but it really is that simple. I have heavily edited code to show the point of the indexing.

```
uint64_t ** find_difference(unsigned char * larger_base,
                              uint64_t size,
                              unsigned char * smaller_base,
                              uint64_t tmap_size)
{
    uint64_t len = size < tmap_size?size:tmap_size;
    uint64_t index=0;
    while(index<len)
    {
            uint64_t larger_num = *(uint64_t*)(larger_base+index);
            uint64_t smaller_num = *(uint64_t*)(smaller_base+index);
            if(larger_num > smaller_num)
            {
                ... do stuff
            }
            index++;
    }

    ...
}
```

Edit#2: Now that I am thinking about it, is it poissible that the pointer dereference goes beyond len? It was my understanding that x86 numbers are stored from high to low addresses. Thus in memory, a number 0x01020304 is stored as 0x04 0x03 0x02 0x01. Is this correct? If this is not true, the deference would go beyond the end of the buffer. However, in GDB I verified the address is accessible.

Comment: Some more code within the context would help us.

Comment: Please elaborate more on smaller_base and index types.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how you use find_difference() function and what values of parameters passed to the function, but I suspect that your pointer arithmetic is wrong.

You are incrementing large_base and smaller_base by 1 and casting resulting address as u64*.
If size is in bytes, then you should check that large_base+index+8 < size.

Comment: size is the size of the buffers in bytes. I think your comment is similar to my question for my second edit and is correct. The index will use 8 bytes past the end of the buffer for index = size-1. I'll verify and get back. Bah, it is so simple, thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Comment: confirmed my pointer math is screwed up would check the right hand boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Your original pointer arithmetic added **index** to a **(unsigned char *)** before casting it to **uint64_t** causing an unaligned memory load, i.e. trying to dereference an **(uint64_t *)** from an address that is not a multiple of 8. This works in the debugger but causes a SEGFAULT in your program.